# React Native Pass Firebase Object To Next Page - React Navigation

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-navigation

I have a list of firebase objects in a React Native ListView. Please see the code below.

Importing the data from Firebase:

```
getDataForFeed() {

    var feedPosts = this;

    firebase
      .database()
      .ref("/feedPosts/")
      .limitToLast(10)
      .orderByChild('sortingTime')
      .on("child_added", function(data) {
      var newData = [...feedPosts.state.listViewData];
      newData.push(data);
      feedPosts.setState({ listViewData: newData });
    });
}
```

Rendering the data:

```
<ListView

   enableEmptySections
   dataSource={this.ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.listViewData)}

   renderRow={data => (

   <Card style={{ flex: 0 }}>

       <CardItem
       button
       onPress={data => {
       this.props.navigation.navigate("ViewPost", {
       subject: data.val().subject //This doesn't work.
      });
     }}
    >

      <Body>
         <Text small>
            {data.val().subject} //This works.
         </Text>
      </Body>

     </CardItem>

   </Card>
  )}
/>
```

When I put a string or integer in the "subject" value, it works fine, but when I want the value I need, data.val().subject - it throws this error.

```
data.val is not a function.
```

In the text box below, data.val().subject shows just fine.

Please help me get this into the correct format for me to pass it to the next page.

Comment: If you put something other then a string or a function that returns a string doesn't          <Text small>
            {data.val().subject}
</Text>
become problematic?
you should be able to pass any object though. Can you show more of the code? an example of subject being assigned a value that does not work?

Comment: <Text small> {data.val().subject} </Text> works perfectly fine. I've updated the code above to give a little bit more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. This is how I did it:

I brought in the data like this:

```
getDataForFeed() {

var feedPosts = this;

firebase
  .database()
  .ref("/feedPosts/")
  .limitToLast(10)
  .orderByChild('sortingTime')
  .on("child_added", function(data) {
  var newData = [...feedPosts.state.listViewData];
  newData.push(data);
  feedPosts.setState({ listViewData: newData });
});
}
```

I made a separate renderRow function instead of doing it inline:

```
renderRow(data) {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

    return (
      <Card style={{ flex: 0 }}>
        <CardItem
          button
          onPress={() => {
            navigate("ViewPost", data.val());
          }
            }
          bordered
        >
        </CardItem>
      </Card>
    );
  }
```

Then I rendered the list like this:

```
<ListView
   enableEmptySections
   dataSource={this.ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.listViewData)}
   renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
/>
```

Then, on the next page, the data is accessed like this:

```
console.log(this.props.navigation.state.params, "Navigation");
```

I hope this helps. Comment if you need any clarification.